# Initial protocol between Webcam and driver

Tags: windows, video, driver, webcam

Is video data that comes from Webcam to low level USB driver already encoded?
What does the low level webcam driver actually do? What is its main and only minimum mission?
Where can I read the principles or the protocol between the webcam hardware and standard Windows driver?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: My NZ bro :) thanks for your comment. This service doesn't allow to ask just one question, they ask to extend it with description (what you've tried...). Seems like I'll earn Tumbleweed again...maybe it has to be asked on some hardware forum.

Comment: Maybe you should try  http://superuser.com/  And I helped you a little.  :-)

Comment: There is nothing DriectShow or VFW related in this question - removing the tags

Comment: DirectShow is not the number of COM objects. It describes the principles of all encoding types, "any" video camera (not only WEB) principles of digitizing video signal.
15 years ago I used to touch DirectShow in only one little tech - Grabbibg image. If you learn DirectShow from its root, you'll be probably able to answer my question.
If you don't know the answer, then that's not the reason to mark -1.

Comment: @RobertKirk, I have upvoted it, but I think you need to be less confrontational.  It's just the way it is - there is more negativity than positivity because the review queue audit encourages down-voting.  And most people succumb to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, based on 5 webcams, that have bought to understand the difference between them, I can make some conclusions.

**> Is video data that comes from Webcam to low level USB driver already encoded?**

Comment: There is no raw format (first part of your answer), which is somehow RGB and then appears to be YUY2 or similar. The data on the wire is already YUY2. This can be clearly seen on certain cameras delivering video in formats, where RGB counterpart would exceed USB 2.0 bandwidth and would be impossible to stream in raw RGB. Similarly, certain [higher end] cameras stream Motion JPEG or H.264 already encoded in hardware. There is no software encoding, video APIs just forward what camera driver can offer, and it takes data "as is" from the wire (in most cases, it can do some minor only conversion).

Comment: Hi Roman, then how do you explain, that 5 different cams of different manufacturers and different prices, connected to the same USB, at the end of WDM offered the same YUY2? It didn't offer nor YVYU nor YUYV nor any other that are similar?
4 of them are brand new, and another 2 (1 was unable to start) from 2010..

Comment: It is logically correct if the driver unifies all incoming formats into one compressed, until someone is not asked to get raw data (RGB) - Motion JPEG.
USB2.0 has speed 480 Mbit/sec, so 640*480 * 24 = about 8 Mb = 60 frames/sec - it's enough for Webcam, but for professional cam it should be hardware coded, and there must be specific driver for that cam, or even SPDIF or FireWire interface, not USB2, maybe USB3.0

Comment: Otherwise, if Wbcam emmits coded signal YUY2 (which is not much less than 24bpp RGB) then you don't know what hardware is used and WDM doesn't guarantee that it will be able to find the proper decoder.
But in case of RGB - it will work 100%.

Comment: > video APIs just forward what camera driver can offer, and it takes data "as is" from the wire
I agree if we have the particular Webcam NATIVE driver installed, but in case of usbvideo.sys (WDM, standard Win7 driver set) it is not clear.
It doesn't know what Webcam is plugged, what format is it going to be received, but it works with any webcam.
Therefore Raw fiormat is logically more suitable, because it's universal.

Comment: Pls, read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webcam Technology Part "Typically, each frame is transmitted uncompressed in RGB or YUV or compressed as JPEG."
I am sure that additional compression will require a chip on Webcam board, and the chip Webcam they are chip because they do not code signal. Just raw RGB. Or I'm not sure, but YUV might be also uncompressed, maybe there is some hardware logic of getting signal in YUV as raw data.

Comment: On USB 2.0 bandwidth: [Web cameras use USB isochronous pipes.  An isochronous pipe is limited to 24MB/s, which is 192 Mbps.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b4c0703a-ac2a-4c70-91d0-7e3897eb4a88/performance-difference-in-windows-7-and-windows-xp-for-the-preview-rendering-of-1080p-video-using?forum=windowsdirectshowdevelopment). If fives yours are YUY2 it does not mean there are no other. YUY2 is simply a recommended format now. [This one](http://www.sensoray.com/USB_H.264_Video_Capture_2253.htm) does UYVY and it's USB.

Comment: And then YUY2 is apparently significantly more compact than RGB, 16 bpp vs. 24 bpp.

Comment: The chippest Webcam I believe sends RGB 24bpp or 16 bpp (565 555).
The standard driver (WDM) unifies it to YUY2. In your case, the device will operate only under control of its native driver. It is hardware video signal processor, sure it will work faster than any software. I asked about minimum sequence - Webcam and WDM driver.

Comment: This week I'll ask my friend in HK, he's NFC engineer. Sure he has someone who's familiar with that tech. Then I'll edit the answer.